# What is the link to get photos in a user album using the graph api?

Tags: java, android, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the graph API to fetch the photos from facebook and display in my Android application.
I'm able to get the JSON of the albums by using 
`https://graph.facebook.com/[USERID]/albums?access_token=[ACCESSTOKEN]`
and able to parse the json and get the name and id of the albums. 
But when I pass the album id to get the pictures in the album using `https://graph.facebook.com/[ALBUMID]/photos`, it is returning a blank json.

```
Main Json

"data": [
  {
     "id": "123456",
     "from": {
        "name": "My Name",
        "id": "560123317"
     },
     "name": "My Photos",
     "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=123456&id=560123317&aid=474294",
     "privacy": "everyone",
     "type": "app",
     "created_time": "2012-12-15T00:47:58+0000",
     "updated_time": "2012-12-15T00:48:57+0000",
     "can_upload": false
  },]
```

The id I am passing is `123456` to `https://graph.facebook.com/[ALBUMID]/photos` and it is returning a blank json although the album has images in it.
Please point out if I am doing something wrong and help me in rectifying the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix to the problem
I had to use `https://graph.facebook.com/<albumid>/photos?access_token=<token>` instead of `https://graph.facebook.com/<albumid>/photos`
By using the complete url with the access token, I am now able to fetch the photos in my albums.

Answer (score 0):

The app may not have permission to access that album. It could be an album created by another application.

`"type": "app"` suggests that the album is an application album.
`"can_upload": false` means that the app doesn't have permission to put photos there. This could be because of a lack of permissions or it could be because it only "[returns true if the user owns the album, the album is not full, and the app can add photos to the album](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/#fields)".

Also, are you using an access token on behalf of the user that owns the album, or someone else? All users have the ability to prevent applications from accessing their things by way of their friends when using the "friends_" permissions.

Comment: The Json there is a part of my facebook album. I am using my Facebook.getAccessToken() to access my facebook album and the app is also the one that I created.

Comment: So even for  `{"id": "123456",
         "from": {
            "name": "My Name",
            "id": "560123317"
         },
         "name": "Timeline Photos",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=123456&id=560123317&aid=99364",
         "cover_photo": "10151135252308318",
         "privacy": "everyone",
         "count": 18,
         "type": "wall",
         "created_time": "2009-08-07T04:23:33+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-10-08T16:36:34+0000",
         "can_upload": false,}` it doesn't return the desired values.Thanks for your help in debugging @AndrewF